# Google chrome memory rise when using canvas. Perhaps a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, memory-leaks

In my application I use an hidden videoplayer as source and copy frame by frame into a canvas so I can edit/crop etc..

It has been working fine for one year.. but since 10 days or so, I'm experiencing a strange behavior with google chrome:

At each frame memory keeps increasing and it's never released.
In task manager I can see the memory assigned to the process rise up to 700MB where it eventually stops growing but at this point page is super slow and I have to close the browser tab

I am 100% sure that 1 month ago this was not happening (I looked at the performance at that time and memory was constant)
I am 100% sure the operation that cause the memory to grow is the drawImage on the canvas (commenting out that single line of code will remove the problem)
This is not happening on firefox

**Someone else is experiencing that?**

**Is there a bug in new version of google chrome?**

A side from that **How can I force the memory to be released?**

I tried by removing the canvas and any reference to that but it's pointless.

For anyone who wants to give it a try, here is the minimum code required to reproduce the issue.
A page with a video player, when video starts playing a canvas is created and attached to the body and each frame is copied.

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video id="VideoElement" controls>
            <source src="test.webm"
                    type='video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"'/>
        </video>
    </body>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</html>
```

code.js:

```
    var VideoManager = (function () {
    function VideoManager() {
        var _this = this;
        this.canvas = null;
        this.videoElement = null;
        this.context = null;
        this.videoElement = document.getElementById('VideoElement');
        this.videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
            _this.copyFrame();
        }, false);
    }

    VideoManager.prototype.copyFrame = function () {
        if (!this.canvas) {
            this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            this.canvas.width = this.videoElement.videoWidth;
            this.canvas.height = this.videoElement.videoHeight;
            document.getElementsByTagName("Body")[0].appendChild(this.canvas);
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        }
        this.context.drawImage(this.videoElement, 0, 0, this.videoElement.videoWidth, this.videoElement.videoHeight);
    };
    return VideoManager;
}());
var videoManager = new VideoManager();
```

Thanks!